# Derive `Show` instances with operations such as "field label modifier" or "constructor tag modifier"

Tags: haskell

We have functions like [`fieldLabelModifier`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=fieldLabelModifier), [`constructorTagModifier`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=constructorTagModifier) when trying to derive for instances such as `aeson`'s `FromJSON` or `swagger2`'s `ToSchema` etc.

[`deriving-aeson`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deriving-aeson-0.2.9) provides a way to achieve the same using generic programming and `DerivingVia` extension.

Is there some library to provide for similar when deriving `Show` instances? Suppose when one wants to get rid of common prefix present in the data constructors? Or is there some concern / fundamental issues with it? I think one can write a way to achieve it "automatically" like how `fieldLabelModifier` does for in above using Template Haskell or generic programming.

Comment: I don't know It there is a library for doing so, I guess no (at least a commonly used one). The reason is that compiler's `Show` and `Read` are mutual inverses, meaning: `x == read (show x)`. Hence, most haskellers aren't willing to break that behaviour for the `Show` typeclass.  However, there are packages with pretty-print type classes. Just go to hackage an search for "pretty" keyword. I don't know if any of those do implement your behaviour.

Comment: @Ismor I had been thinking about it, and I think such a library could allow deriving for both `Show` & `Read` like how `deriving-aeson` allows deriving for both `FromJSON` & `ToJSON` under same rules.

Comment: Sure, you could derive both types classes in `aeson` style. My point is that such a library wouldn't be used. The haskell community mostly use `Show` (and sometimes `Read`) for debugging purposes. If you want to show your data type to the user (ex: on logging or error messages) then a prettyprinter or json serialization is a much better approach. So I'd say there isn't a real use case for such a library other than a personal preference when debugging.